# Is it possible to change sort of Tableau filters

Tags: tableau-api

I have a tableau worksheet where I have a visible filter on 'year's.  The natural sort of the drop-down is ascending order.  I would like to change the order to be in descending order--most recent at top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, have a look at the following link.

https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/sorting-quick-filter-values

Here is the relevent details from the link.

Answer

- Ensure that the data to be sorted is not currently filtered. Any data
  being filtered when the manual sort is set will not be a part of the
  manual sort settings.
- From the Data pane (where the Dimensions and Measures are displayed)
  right-click the field that you want to format, and then select
  Default Properties > Sort.
- Select Manual, adjust the sort order, and then click OK. For more
  information, see Sort.
  Additional Information

  These steps will not work for filters created from date fields.